# How to express cpp-like string with regex (lexical analysis)

Tags: c++, regex, analysis, lexical

I am writing a cpp program that is a lexical analyzer for a cpp-like language. To find each token, I use a regex to match and then decide to choose the right token.

Strings in this language are exactly like cpp. The regex that I use is like this:

```
\"([^\\\"]|\\.)?\"
```

But it is not really correct. For an input like this:

```
"String \" int"
```

The output should be one string token, but with my regex I get one string token ("String ") and an int keyword, and then an error.

Do you have any idea how to handle this? Or how should I change the regex?

P.S. : I use regex_search() to find the match.

Thank you.

Comment: `"String \" int"` string literal does not contain ``\`` char. Use `string s=R"String \\\" int";` - but your pattern handles single quotes and your sample string has double quotes.

Comment: @Gurman No. String `"String"String"` is not acceptable. But your regex accepts that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My sample just shows what appears in console, and I meant exactly what your code means. (Also I edited my regex. It was my mistake.)

Comment: Ok, try `R"('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. This works. Actually using raw string for regex is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
std::regex rx(R"(\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\")");
```

The pattern is `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`:

- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than a double quote and backslash
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\\.` - any char with a backslash in front (replace `.` with `[\s\S]` to if you need to also support escaped line breaks)
  - `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than a double quote and backslash
- `"` - double quote.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Qs0gLH/2).